# How to auto increase versioning so that browser can automatically reload the JS/CSS files without having to clear the cache manually

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, auto-versioning

I am totally new in React Js. Currently I need to auto update the version number whenever I build so that the browser can automatically reload the JS/CSS files without having to clear the cache manually. Is there any way to do this? I searched but most of it is for .net answers. Really appreciate any guidance and helps..Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can easily do this with a small NPM package that is already pre-built

https://richhewlett.com/2020/07/11/auto-increment-build-number-in-a-javascript-app/

Comment: thanks, let me try and will let you know :)

Comment: my generate-buildno.js is not getting called.. for now i simply put alert message, but it is not called..

Answer (score 0):

There is also an npm package named [`auto-version-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-version-js) which allows you to automatically increase your version number :

```py
npx auto-version --patch  # +0.0.1
npx auto-version --minor  # +0.1.0
npx auto-version --major  # +1.0.0
```

To implement it in your `package.json` file :

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev:patch": "npx auto-version --patch",
  "dev:minor": "npx auto-version --minor",
  "dev:major": "npx auto-version --major"
}
```

The documentation is available [here](https://github.com/d0rianb/auto-version-js/blob/master/README.md).